# Rails email is sending as myself

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

I have a contact form where the user inputs his name, email, and message but when they hit submit it sends the message to my email from me. I assume its because of

```
 config.action_mailer.smtp_settings ={
      address: 'smtp.gmail.com',
      port: 587,
      domain: 'example.com',
      authentication: 'plain',
      enable_starttls_auto: trust,
      user_name: 'railstest77@gmail.com',
      password: 'testtest77'
   }
```

how can i get it to send from the users account in rails 5.0. I've tried using mail_form with no success,is there a recommended way to send an email from the user

Comment: Did you check [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that Gmail isn't a general purpose email service provider in the way you're attempting to use it. The SMTP gateway they provide is only really there to facilitate sending personal email via an arbitrary email client (besides Gmail's web client).

It isn't intended to send email on behalf of others. You might want to check out services like [AWS SES](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/) or others. They are much more practical than managing your own email server.